# Google Sheets Formula for Condition based on Current Month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I've been struggling with this formula for a few days now. I'd like to return a specified cell based on the current month. For example: If it's January return AC5, if its February return AC6, march returns AC7, etc.

I'm using *=MONTH(NOW())* to return the number of the month in cell T2, but just can't figure out where to go from here. Can you have more than one condition in an IF statement? I can't get past the idea that if the month equals "1" its true (so use January) but if it's false what would it do?

Is this even possible to do in Google Sheets?

**EDIT: I found a formula that works! It is long and ugly but it works correctly:**

=IF(T2=1,AC5,IF(T2=2,AC6,IF(T2=3,AC7,IF(T2=4,AC8,IF(T2=4,AC9,IF(T2=5,AC9,IF(T2=6,AC10,IF(T2=7,AC11,IF(T2=8,AC12,IF(T2=9,AC13,IF(T2=10,AC14,IF(T2=11,AC15,IF(T2=12,AC16,poop)))))))))))))

I nested the IF statement to death, but it does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use separate table:

```
1  AC5
2  AC6
3  AC7
...
```

and Vlookup it:
= vlookup(MONTH(NOW()), A:B, 2, 0)

to return the value, use Indirect:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(MONTH(NOw()),A:B,2,0))
```

Here's [workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-IUztVK5rzWKPOakCTV4ornf20fWP4W0DTzpheqwbY/edit?usp=sharing)